# Developing a django project that uses a third party DBAL package

Tags: python, django, database-connection

I am writing a django project, that makes extensive use of a python package I'm writing (let's call it foo, for convenience).

The python package foo, will consist mainly of functions and classes that munge data obtained from a backend database. I want to write the package in such a way that it will have no dependency on django - and can be used in other projects outside of django.

I am thinking of writing the package so that functions accept a database connection - and classes uses IoC for the database connection - that way, I can obtain a database connection from django and pass it to the DBAL package - when using it in django, and instantiate a DB connection via other means when using the package outside django.

I have two questions:

1. Is this an acceptable way of approaching this problem (i.e. no gotchas)
2. Where/how do I obtain a database connection within django?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get a cursor object from Django like so:

```
from django.db import connection

def my_custom_sql(self):
    with connection.cursor() as cursor:
        cursor.execute("UPDATE bar SET foo = 1 WHERE baz = %s", [self.baz])
        cursor.execute("SELECT foo FROM bar WHERE baz = %s", [self.baz])
        row = cursor.fetchone()

    return row
```

This example is taken from their docs for custom SQL queries [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/db/sql/#executing-custom-sql-directly)

In terms of being an acceptable way to write a package, sure. It's just a loose form of [Dependency Injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_injection) and makes unit testing much easier, for one thing.

The only 'gotcha' is that the cursors passed in by users of your package may not present the same interface. SQLAlchemy cursors may not have the same properties and methods as Django ORM cursors.

I'd say ensuring that the object conforms to your required interface is an acceptable burden to push onto users, as long as you thoroughly document what that object should expose.

You can always provide custom workarounds for the most popular options in future, if you find it would be valuable to do so. (e.g. provide your own cursor adaptor classes).